# Alternating Series formula

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm having an issue with the following alternating series.

$\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{5} + \frac{1}{10} - \frac{1}{17} \text{ } ...$

Can't for the life of me figure out how to come up with the $bn$ for the series,

Comment: Substract 1 from the denominator. Can you see a pattern now?

Comment: $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2+2n+2}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^2+1}$$ I think you can use Residue theorem hereon.

Comment: @MartinR But perhaps the $n$-th denominator is the sum of the first $n$ prime numbers?

Comment: Hmmmph.  In my opinion, it's not *your* (or my or any readers) job to figure out the $b_n$ for the series.  It's the job of the person asking the question.  *our* job is to figure out if it converges and if so to what, but if we don't even know what the series *is* we can't be expected to do it.  Math isn't a bunch of "ha, I gothcha!" riddles.

Comment: @Whatsup Only the next term of the given series could clear the doubt.

Comment: .... Then again, the $2 = 1^2 + 1$ and $5 = 2^2 + 1$ and $10 = 3^2 + 1$ and $17 = 4^2 + 1$ so $b_n = (-1)^{n+1}\frac 1{n^2 + 1}$ does seem to be the pattern.... so now the ball is back in our court.

Comment: @MartinR Yes, thank you a lot for that. I considered going that way but I discarded that thought before even trying it out.

Comment: "But perhaps the n-th denominator is the sum of the first n prime numbers?"  Well, there *are* infinite optios it could be.  "Only the next term of the given series could clear the doubt. "  Well, it would rule out one or the other or both... but it wouldn't (and couldn't) declare it *must* be this one.

Comment: @fleablood By that comment I was trying to express what you stated, and above all the bad quality of the question (:

Comment: I'm not sure why you would discard "the denominator is one more than the square" without even trying it.  It's very clearly a strong pattern and probably one that can be solved.  My issue is, it is not valid to present three, or four, or 57 terms and expect the pattern to be clear.  There are an *infinite* (*uncountably* infinite) number of series that start with the same $n$ terms and even though there is a pattern the first 2,987 might follow that does not mean the next term will follow it.  There are *still* uncountably many  series with the same 2,987 first terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^2+1}$$